# Does configure --disable-shared work with tcl 8.6.3? Need static libtcl8.6.a

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, tcl, configure

My goal is to build a static libtcl8.6.a

So I just tried to build tcl8.6.3 with

```
./configure --enable-threads --disable-shared --enable-symbols=mem
```

Then I linked my app to libtcl8.6.a.  But when I run the app I get this output:

> error while loading shared libraries: libtcl8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   It's as if the --disable-shared config was ignored.

Is that expected with tcl 8.6.3?

Comment: That's not a tcl build problem. That's a your app linking problem. How did you link your app to tcl? What does `ldd` say about your app?

Answer (score 1):

As @Etan suggested, I re-linked the app and the problem went away.

My failing version of the app was linked through soft-links (using ln) so I didn't have to disturb the build environment too much when upgrading from 8.4.11 to 8.6.3.

My working version did way with the soft-links and instead updated the build environment to properly link to 8.6.3 directly.